# list of all permuations of sublists of a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I've got a certain class of lists with, say, 4 elements, that are lists themselves. E.g. `{{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}`.
I'd like to find a way to generate a list that contains all of the cousins of this list where the sublists are permuted in all possible ways.
With the previous example, this list would have size $3!\times 2!=12$.

To be really definite, in the simpler case of `{{1, 2},{3,4}}`, I'd want to obtain `{{{1, 2},{3,4}},{{2,1},{3,4}},{{1, 2},{4,3}},{{2,1},{4,3}}}`.

I feel like there should be a one line code for this but I couldn't figure it out.

`Permutations/@{{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}` returns a reasonably interesting list, out of which I'm unable to extract what I want in a simple (i.e. Mathematica) way. Using further `Pick` starts to demand that I get more explicitly certain lists or binary trees or so...

Comment: Does `Tuples[Permutations /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}]` suit your needs?

Comment: @J.M. Oh... `Tuples` is so much simpler than `Outer` for this... If you post that as an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: It's not too late to edit your answer, @Martin. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Yes it does ! Please put this as an answer. I also like very much the explanation with Outer below.

Comment: @Martin Büttner well it is simpler yes but I'm also happy that I learned about Outer today as well !

Comment: `Distribute[Permutations /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}, List]` is another possibility

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is the outer product of all the lists returned by `Permutations /@ ...`. You can use `Outer` for that. The only issue is that `Outer` returns the result as a nested list (basically an n-dimensional table of all the possible permutations), so you'll have to flatten it afterwards:

```
lists = {{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}};
Flatten[Outer[List, ##, 1] & @@ Permutations /@ lists, Length@lists - 1]

(* {{{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {6, 5}, {7}}, 
    {{1, 3, 2}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}, {{1, 3, 2}, {4}, {6, 5}, {7}}, 
    {{2, 1, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}, {{2, 1, 3}, {4}, {6, 5}, {7}}, 
    {{2, 3, 1}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}, {{2, 3, 1}, {4}, {6, 5}, {7}}, 
    {{3, 1, 2}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}, {{3, 1, 2}, {4}, {6, 5}, {7}}, 
    {{3, 2, 1}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {4}, {6, 5}, {7}}} *)
```

---

Well if this is now the accepted answer, I might as well edit in J. M.'s solution for completeness. The above is essentially a manual reimplementation of the built-in `Tuples` so that's all you need:

```
Tuples[Permutations /@ lists]
```